# multiple input text more than 50 how to get result from one ajax request?

Tags: php, ajax

```
    <?php include('db.php') ?>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<?php include('header.php') ?>

<body>


    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-12 col-lg-12">
            <table class="table table-bordered " id="invoiceItem">
                <!-- table-hover -->
                <tr>
                    <th width="2%"><input id="checkAll" class="formcontrol" type="checkbox"></th>
                    <th width="20%">ItemNo </th>
                    <th width="38%">ItemName</th>
                    <th width="10%">OnHand </th>
                    <th width="10%">Quantity</th>
                    <th width="10%">Price </th>
                    <th width="10%">Total </th>
                </tr>
                <?php
                $i = 1;

                while ($i < 51) {
                ?>
                    <tr>
                        <td><input class="itemRow" type="checkbox"></td>
                        <td><input type="text" class="form-control" name="productCode[]" id="productCode_<?php echo $i; ?>"></input></td>
                        <td><input readonly type="text" name="productName[]" id="productName_<?php echo $i; ?>" class="form-control" autocomplete="off"></td>
                        <td><input readonly type="number" name="productOnHand[]" id="productOnHand_<?php echo $i; ?>" class="form-control" autocomplete="off"></td>
                        <td><input type="number" min="0" name="quantity[]" id="quantity_<?php echo $i; ?>" class="form-control quantity" value="" autocomplete="off"></td>
                        <td><input readonly type="number" name="price[]" id="price_<?php echo $i; ?>" class="form-control price" autocomplete="off"></td>
                        <td><input readonly type="number" name="total[]" id="total_<?php echo $i; ?>" class="form-control total" readonly autocomplete="off"></td>

                    </tr>
                <?php
                    $i++;
                }
                ?>


            </table>
        </div>
    </div>




   <script>
        $(document).ready(function() {
            
   

            $("#productCode_1").focus();

           

            document.getElementById("productCode_1").addEventListener('change', () => {

                var PID = $("#productCode_1").val();
                getDataFromServer(PID);
                $("#productCode_2").focus();

            });


            document.getElementById("productCode_2").addEventListener('change', () => {

                var PID = $("#productCode_2").val();
                getDataFromServer2(PID);
                $("#productCode_3").focus();

            });

            document.getElementById("productCode_3").addEventListener('change', () => {

                var PID = $("#productCode_3").val();
                getDataFromServer3(PID);
                // $("#productCode_2").focus();

            });








            function getDataFromServer(PID) {

                $.ajax({
                    type: "POST",
                    url: "response.php",
                    data: {
                        pro_id: PID
                    },
                    success: function(response) {
                        const JSON_Obj = JSON.parse(response);
                        $('#productName_1').val(JSON_Obj.pro_name);
                        $('#productOnHand_1').val(JSON_Obj.pro_quantity);
                        $('#price_1').val(JSON_Obj.pro_price);
                        $("#quantity_1").val(1);
                        // calculateTotal();
                    }
                });
            }


            function getDataFromServer2(PID) {

                $.ajax({
                    type: "POST",
                    url: "response.php",
                    data: {
                        pro_id: PID
                    },
                    success: function(response) {
                        const JSON_Obj = JSON.parse(response);
                        $('#productName_2').val(JSON_Obj.pro_name);
                        $('#productOnHand_2').val(JSON_Obj.pro_quantity);
                        $('#price_2').val(JSON_Obj.pro_price);
                        $("#quantity_2").val(1);
                        // calculateTotal();
                    }
                });
            }

            function getDataFromServer3(PID) {

                $.ajax({
                    type: "POST",
                    url: "response.php",
                    data: {
                        pro_id: PID
                    },
                    success: function(response) {
                        const JSON_Obj = JSON.parse(response);
                        $('#productName_3').val(JSON_Obj.pro_name);
                        $('#productOnHand_3').val(JSON_Obj.pro_quantity);
                        $('#price_3').val(JSON_Obj.pro_price);
                        $("#quantity_3").val(1);
                        // calculateTotal();
                    }
                });
            }

          
        }); // document.ready
    </script>





</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Where exactly are you stuck? Explain the expected result and what currently happens (details incl. errors.) Also read [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) and [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). You should also [take the tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) that was recommended to you when you registered. Is the issue with your JS code or your PHP code (which you have omitted)?

Comment: Thanks M. Eriksson i stuck on the numbers of ajax request how to do it by one ajax request ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to add class inside the inputs and need to handle the request with the class . Just a quick check changes on your code, for exact need please modify as per your requirement just follow concept -

```
<?php include('db.php') ?>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<?php include('header.php') ?>

<body>


    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-12 col-lg-12">
            <table class="table table-bordered " id="invoiceItem">
                <!-- table-hover -->
                <tr>
                    <th width="2%"><input id="checkAll" class="formcontrol" type="checkbox"></th>
                    <th width="20%">ItemNo </th>
                    <th width="38%">ItemName</th>
                    <th width="10%">OnHand </th>
                    <th width="10%">Quantity</th>
                    <th width="10%">Price </th>
                    <th width="10%">Total </th>
                </tr>
                <?php
                $i = 1;

                while ($i < 51) {
                ?>
                    <tr>
                        <td><input class="itemRow" type="checkbox"></td>
                        <td><input type="text" class="form-control product-code" name="productCode[]" id="productCode_<?php echo $i; ?>" data-id="<?php echo $i; ?>"></input></td>
                        <td><input readonly type="text" name="productName[]" id="productName_<?php echo $i; ?>" class="form-control product-name" autocomplete="off" data-id="<?php echo $i; ?>"></td>
                        <td><input readonly type="number" name="productOnHand[]" id="productOnHand_<?php echo $i; ?>" class="form-control product-on-hand" autocomplete="off" data-id="<?php echo $i; ?>"></td>
                        <td><input type="number" min="0" name="quantity[]" id="quantity_<?php echo $i; ?>" class="form-control quantity" value="" autocomplete="off" data-id="<?php echo $i; ?>"></td>
                        <td><input readonly type="number" name="price[]" id="price_<?php echo $i; ?>" class="form-control price" autocomplete="off" data-id="<?php echo $i; ?>"></td>
                        <td><input readonly type="number" name="total[]" id="total_<?php echo $i; ?>" class="form-control total" readonly autocomplete="off" data-id="<?php echo $i; ?>"></td>

                    </tr>
                <?php
                    $i++;
                }
                ?>


            </table>
        </div>
    </div>




   <script>

        jQuery(document).on('click','.product-code', function(){
            var PID = jQuery(this).val();
            var itemId = jQuery(this).attr('data-id');
            var nextItemId = parseInt(itemId) + 1;
            getDataFromServer(PID,itemId);
            jQuery("#productCode_"+nextItemId).focus();
        })

        
        function getDataFromServer(PID,itemId) {

            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "response.php",
                data: {
                    pro_id: PID
                },
                success: function(response) {
                    const JSON_Obj = JSON.parse(response);
                    $('#productName_'+itemId).val(JSON_Obj.pro_name);
                    $('#productOnHand_'+itemId).val(JSON_Obj.pro_quantity);
                    $('#price_'+itemId).val(JSON_Obj.pro_price);
                    $("#quantity_"+itemId).val(1);
                    // calculateTotal();
                }
            });
        }
    </script>


</body>

</html>
```

Comment: That's what I want exactly -thanks allot

Comment: I think now  make HTML rows added by JS before  jumping to next  input  i think its better than make it 50 row